# NSNumberFormatter trims values on encountering zero after decimal

Tags: objective-c, nsnumberformatter, nsdecimalnumber, currency-formatting

It can be a duplicate question,but whatever i found it didn't help me.

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setGroupingSeparator:@","];
[numberFormatter setGroupingSize:3];
[numberFormatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
[numberFormatter setDecimalSeparator:@"."];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
NSString *theString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:num];
```

I'm using this for thousands string conversion.But if i pass values like 5123.00 it converts it to 5,123,but i need all the decimal values(like 5,123.00) after decimal point, even it is zero.
How to do this,please provide some solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
[numberFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
```